# Handson table and Rulejs autofill formulas

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel-formula, handsontable

I would like to autofill a column with formula based on say C1 and C2 cell from within code (not my manually double clicking or dragging)

Comment: What have you tried? What does your code look like now? I something not working with your code?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to leverage the Autofill (apply) plugin and finally found how to use it. Here is the code to set a formula for column "C" and apply it to top 10 rows from within the code

`var hot = $('#TableContainer').handsontable('getInstance');
 hot.setDataAtCell(1,2,"=sum(A2,b2)"); // 1,2 is C2
 hot.selectCell(1,2, 1,2); // select C2 and apply this formula
 hot.autofill.instance.view.wt.selections.fill.add(new WalkontableCellCoords(1, 2));
 hot.autofill.instance.view.wt.selections.fill.add(new WalkontableCellCoords(9, 2));
 hot.autofill.apply(); // applies formula to the coords C2 to C10`